# Using Powershell how do you get the weekday number?

Tags: powershell

Using a Powershell date object how do you get the day number of the week, 0 to 6 where 0 would be Sunday and 6 would be Saturday. I know that I can get the day name with the code below but how do I get the number as there is no DayNumberOfWeek or equivalent property?

```
(Get-Date).DayOfWeek
```

I suppose I could use the day name from the code above in a switch statement to convert it to a number but that doesn't seem to be very eloquent.

Comment: Just FYI; 0 is Monday in some countries and Sunday in others. It depends on the culture(regional settings) of the computer.

Comment: @FrodeF. This can be determined with [`(Get-WinSystemLocale).DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/international/get-winsystemlocale), [`[Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::CurrentInfo.FirstDayOfWeek`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo), or [`[Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek`](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo).  For .NET's [`DayOfWeek` enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.dayofweek), though, `0` is _always_ `Sunday`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

like this:

```
( get-date ).DayOfWeek.value__
```

I suggest for the future to investigate what properties an object in this way:

```
( get-date ).DayOfWeek | gm -f # gm is an alias for get-member
```

Comment: Yes just discovered it myself - just needed to drill down another level. Cheers anyway.

Comment: Was just waiting for the time limit to expire.

Comment: I want to filter for certain days of week (only weekdays) but it does not work if I format the date beforehand (date is piped to where). The where works if I do not format. Any help?

Answer (score 29):

Well, the `DayOfWeek` property of a `DateTime` is not a string but rather a `DayOfWeek` enum, so the shortest answer is probably

```
[Int] (Get-Date).DayOfWeek  # returns 0 through 6 for current day of week
```

Or

```
[Int] [DayOfWeek] "Wednesday"  # returns 3
```

Comment: *`powershell [Int] (Get-Date).DayOfWeek`* does work (returns "1" for "Monday"). But, I tried *`powershell [Int] [DayOfWeek] "Wednesday"`*, exactly as you have written it, but powershell shows an error: **"`Unexpected token 'Wednesday' in expression or statement."`**

Comment: Run from the PowerShell prompt, not from the cmd.exe prompt (i.e., don't prefix the command with `powershell`). (Why do you think you need to do that? My example doesn't have it.)

Comment: @KevinFegan Use `::` *Static member operator* when calling from command prompt as follows: `powershell [Int][DayOfWeek]::"Wednesday"` (or even without quotes `powershell [Int][DayOfWeek]::Wednesday`).

Answer (score 6):

```
Get-Date -UFormat %u
```

will return formated date.

check http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx for more fomats

Answer (score 1):

On Friday the 17th:

```
(get-date).DayOfWeek.value__
```

Returns `5`

```
(Get-Date).DayOfWeek
```

Returns `Friday`

```
(Get-Date).Day
```

Returns `17`

Comment: (Get-Date).Day returns the Day of Month